# How to remove records based on frequency of three way interaction using awk

Tags: awk

How to remove records when the frequency of three-way interaction of the factors (V2*V3*V4) is below 5.

original data

```
ID V2 V3 V4
101 2012 5 1
101 2012 5 1
101 2012 5 1
101 2012 5 1
102 2010 12 2
102 2012 12 2
102 2012 12 2
102 2012 12 2
```

Comment: Does data in your actual input follow the same pattern i.e. _the same ID_ for the three-way interaction of _the same factors_ ? Or is it possible to have a line like `105 2012 5 1` further down in your sample input (that is the same factors but different ID) ?

Comment: @don_crissti- Yes. the Id could vary.

Answer (score 2):

Since "V2" is over 2,000 and no other columns are below 1, the product of those columns will always be greater than five given your sample data.  However:

```
awk '($2*$3*$4) > 5 { print } NR==1 { print }' /path/to/data
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the math for frequency, but I do like awk! Here is a script that iterates through every record of your test file and performs multiplications on the numbers, and compares them to see if they are less than 5. If less than 5, don't print. Otherwise print.

`#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  print "ID V2 V3 V4 = PRODUCT";
}
{
  TOTAL = int($1 * $2 * $3);
  if(TOTAL < 5)
  {
    # Don't print
  }
  else
  {
    print $1,"",$2,"",$3,"=",TOTAL;
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Since the ID could vary for the same factors, you could read the file twice - first to count how many times you have `V2_V3_V4` and then again to check each line and print only if the count from the 1st pass was greater than or equal to `n` (in this case 5):

```
awk -vn=5 'NR==FNR{++z[$2"_"$3"_"$4];next};
FNR==1{print;next};z[$2"_"$3"_"$4]>=n' infile infile
```